# Populate 3 ListViews from a Database in three Fragments

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm working on an app that allows the user to add an item to a list (todo list). The user has the choise of which list the item will go into. The app uses Tabbed Views (Simular to Skype), and I need to be able to populate the lists from the Database (SQLite).

My MainActivity.java :

```
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
    import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import static com.example.todo.Constants.*;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.List;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private static String[] FROM = { _ID, TODO_TEXT, LOCATION, };
    private static int[] TO = { R.id.todoTextView };
    private static String ORDER_BY = ORDER + " DESC";
    ListView taskListView;
    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    public Button speakButton;


    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        Context context = this;

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab2);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showAlert();
            }
        });
        Cursor cursor = getEvents();
        showEvents(cursor);

    }

    private void addEvent(String string) {
        // Insert a new record into the Events data source.
        // You would do something similar for delete and update.
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ORDER, System.currentTimeMillis());
        values.put(REMINDER_TEXT, string);
        getContentResolver().insert(CONTENT_URI, values);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    void showAlert(){
        final EditText reminderinput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reminderText);
        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
        adb.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_new_reminder, null))
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // save reminder here
                        Editable reminderText = reminderinput.getText();
                        String reminderTextString = String.valueOf(reminderText);
                        addEvent(reminderTextString);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //it already cancels
                    }
                });
        adb.setTitle("Set a reminder");
        AlertDialog ad = adb.create();
        ad.show();

    }

    private Cursor getEvents() {
        // Perform a managed query. The Activity will handle closing
        // and re-querying the cursor when needed.
        return managedQuery(CONTENT_URI, FROM, null, null, ORDER_BY);
    }

    private void showEvents(Cursor cursor) {
        // Set up data binding
        ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.task_item, cursor, FROM, TO);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AppSettings.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Important";
                case 1:
                    return "Kinda Important";
                case 2:
                    return "Not very Important";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, i have a Constants.java and also some layout files in the project.
Unfortunately, the app throws an error saying:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

HELP!

Answer (score 0):

So you have the listviews in your fragment and you are doing

```
ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
```

This finds the listview in activity_main and not the fragment.
You should populate the listviews in the fragment.
Call this in the fragment.

```
ListView mListView = rootview.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    Cursor cursor = getEvents();
        showEvents(cursor);
```

Comment: The problem is, getEvents() and showEvents() aren't static, and if I make them static, the methods inside of them throw errors.